# PHP files in certain dir result in HTTP 500 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cron

I'm facing a strange situation. For a website some cronjobs are being executed. This all worked well until now; when I try to excecute a cronjob I'm getting no result. For some reason the URL is recognized by .htaccess trying to put it into the site with wrong $_GET parameters. The second parameter is 500. When I try to reach a file which doesn't exist the second parameter becomes 404. So I figured these had to be http response codes.

When using Chrome's Network inspector I see the result for a - should be - working cronjob is a http 500. I'm clueless... Is there any way this might have been set by someone else, by accident, maybe by the ISP somewhere in the php.ini or httpd.conf I can look?

The structure is `http://www.domain.com/CronJobs/file.php`. I've found out it's only happening for files in the `CronJobs` folder. Cronjobs are supposed to be executed using `wget`.

-- Addition

Maybe if it is of any assistance, the rule in the .htaccess being used for the request is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)FCKEditor(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /index.php?pageId=LandingPage&Alias=$1 [L]
```

Obviously no rule should be used and the server should just serve the PHP-file being asked for.

-- Second addition

I also tried to empty the .htaccess-file and then request the cronjob. I still get the error 500. Only this time being served from the PHP-file itself, not from the index.php (which is was used by the original .htaccess contents).

Comment: Is there .htaccess insude CrobJobs folder?

Comment: no, there isn't. and there wasn't one either.

Comment: What's in the htaccess file in your document root?

Comment: You need to check your server logs, 500 indicates an internal server error, there is something wrong in your php code.

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey, it practically can't be; a test-file used just contained plain text saying `hello`. That also resulted in a error 500.

Comment: @JonLin, a bunch of rules. The first rule is to enable the rewrite engine, other contents are just rules for certain URL-scenarios.

Comment: @Ben what do your server logs say for the 500 error in any test case? try dropping a blank .htaccess file in that folder ?

Comment: @Ben: Every 500 should be logged in Apache error logs.

Comment: @anubhava, I've found the problem and answered my own question, hoping it may help others in the future.

Comment: @Ben : Change the FCKEditor !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue, hope this answer helps someone out in the future.

Okay, this one was a bit distracting to find but I found my problem. Permissions.
I've set the folderpermission to 777 while the folder may not be writeable. I've changed to permissions back to 755 and it's working again.

The errors in the logs were all like: `[Mon Oct 21 20:00:01 2013] [warn] Directory "/home/accountname/domains/domain.com/public_html/CronJobs" is writeable by group`

After searching based on that error I came across https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/594 and that's where I saw the permission issue.

(I've set the permissions previously to 777 for a simple lockfile).